# How is intersection implemented in Shapely?

Tags: shapely

I have gone over code and manuals and questions and I can not still find out how exactly the intersection function is implemented in Shapely. Can anyone point me to the right place?

Details:

Does it compare the lat and lng of points of two objects (e.g. lines)? Must the lat lngs of points in two objects match exactly? With what precision should they match?

When I look at the points inside the intersected multipoints object of two linestrings, I can see that the points in the intersection object do not exactly match any of the points on any of the lines which means some rounding has most likely taken place.

Comment: Shapely offers several ways to calculate relationships which could all be loosely grouped as types of intersection in my mind.  If you're referring specifically to  object.intersects(other) then geometric objects intersect if they have any boundary or interior point in common.  Much [more info here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.intersects).

Comment: Per [Shapely's documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#introduction), its implementations use the [Java Topology Suite](https://github.com/locationtech/jts) via [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/)

Comment: If you're intersecting lines, shapely returns the coordinate of their intersections, not the nearest point to the intersection. If you're looking for points that are shared by both lines, I wouldn't use shapely at all. [Note that when I refer to points, I mean the points given to shapely to define a linestring.] You should provide some code and images to demonstrate your problem!

Comment: Thanks all! This was helpful. When two lat longs from two routes are compared, they usually do not match exactly (if you consider all decimal points), but they may do after rounding with some precision. I was wondering if such rounding first takes place. To which decimal number that takes place and so on.

Comment: For future readers who are interested in how JTS/Shapely implements polygon intersection, see my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/411870/193257).