# What is the algorithm that Shapely used to check if two polygons intersect?

Tags: python, polygon, shapely, algorithm, intersect

What is the algorithm that [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) used to check if two polygons intersect?

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
p1 = Polygon([(0,0), (3,0), (3,1), (1,1), (1,2), (3,2), (3,3), (0,3)])
p2 = Polygon([(4,0), (5,0), (5,1.5), (2,1.5), (2,1.2), (4,1.2)])
print(p1.intersects(p2))
```

I had read the source code of Shapely but didn't find the implementation.

Comment: Well, it's open-source, so you can track it down, but according to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306740/how-is-intersection-implemented-in-shapely), your search will take you to JTS.

Comment: Thank you! I have read the source code of the Shapely, but I didn't find the implementation. Thank again for the JTS.

Comment: Please be sure to include all relevant facts in the Question body when you post. The [Tour] has additional details about how GIS SE works.

Comment: Thanks! I have modified the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick search of the [Shapely code base](https://github.com/Toblerity) leads to [`impl.py`](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/shapely/impl.py) which:

> """Implementation of the intermediary layer between Shapely and GEOS
> This is layer number 2 from the list below.
>
> 1. geometric objects: the
>    Python OO API.
> 2. implementation map: an abstraction that permits
>    different backends.
> 3. backend: callable objects that take Shapely
>    geometric objects as arguments    and, with GEOS as a backend,
>    translate them to C data structures.
> 4. GEOS library: algorithms
>    implemented in C++. Shapely 1.2 includes a GEOS backend and it is the
>    default. """

So the next place to look is GEOS and [`Geometry.ccp`](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/blob/7dc03c1a9f7046563e3890dfc1b265e0bd551dd5/src/geom/Geometry.cpp) and it's [`intersection`](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/blob/7dc03c1a9f7046563e3890dfc1b265e0bd551dd5/src/geom/Geometry.cpp#L525) method. This is a wrapper for [`HeuristicOverlay`](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/blob/master/src/geom/HeuristicOverlay.cpp)
which calls [OverlayNGRobust::overlay](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/blob/7dc03c1a9f7046563e3890dfc1b265e0bd551dd5/src/operation/overlayng/OverlayNGRobust.cpp#L84) which is where we start to see references to [JTS](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/), where the [API docs](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/algorithm/package-summary.html) state:

> The obvious naive algorithm for intersection detection (comparing
> every segment with every other) has unacceptably slow performance.
> There is a large literature of faster algorithms for intersection
> detection. Unfortunately, many of them involve substantial code
> complexity. JTS tries to balance code simplicity with performance
> gains. It uses some simple techniques to produce substantial
> performance gains for common types of input data.

After some more poking around in the JTS code we eventually come to [`RelateComputer`](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/operation/relate/RelateComputer.java) which calculates the [`IntersectionMatrix`](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/geom/IntersectionMatrix.java) between two geometries (which includes intersection).

Any deeper than that and you will need to wait for Dr JTS to answer.

Comment: And answer I will, but not with anything better than "read the source code" ATM.  The spatial relationship algorithm is quite complex, and currently there's no good high-level description of it available.  Maybe sometime...

Comment: I will point out that the OverlayNG code is only used for overlay ops (like `intersection`).  The spatial predicates (like `intersects`) are evaluated using an older and completely different codebase (which `RelateComputer` is an entry point for).

Comment: For future readers who are interested in how JTS/Shapely implements polygon intersection, see my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/411870/193257).